# How to best handle data models in an an Android App?

Tags: android, mobile, apk

I have a college project where the idea is to allow gym-goers to record their progress/evolution in several machines/exercises (e.g. first week I ran 6km in the treadmill in 15 minutos; second week I ran 6.5km, and so forth). I want the user to be able to create an activity plan by selecting several machines/exercises from a list, and each machine/exercise has properties (such as repetitions, muscle groups trained, time, weight, distance, etc).

So, my question is: what is the best way to store the different types of machines/exercises on the apk? Is it to create models for each generic type and load them from a local JSON? Define each exercise outside the app and connect it to a database and have the app fetch the list to the user?

In a prior project I created a Truth or Dare game where the questions (truths or dares) where loaded from a local JSON and turned using a factory to actual questions (using a Question model) to display in-game, but I never found out if that's the best/correct approach.

P.S.: there exists both the possibility that the App is solely local OR that it will be connected to a server + db. Unfortunately, due to the nature of the project I cannot give a concrete answer to this question, but would instead appreciate an answer to both cases...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using apk's local storage for data storage/retrieval**

In such case you can either use `JSON` for storage/retrieval or android's `SQLiteDatabase` . If you use `SQLiteDatabase` for storage your app will contain `db` file which is a small database embedded in apk

If your data contains multiple entities related to each other then you have to go for `SQLiteDatabase` as using a plane `JSON` in such case would not be simple

**Using remote storage for data storage/retrieval in apk**

In this case you can setup database server in remote machine for your app.

Or

You can use `Firebase`

It depends what type of app you are making, if user doesn't have to update its exercise progress to remote machine then local `SQLiteDatabase` would be sufficient in your case

Comment: Thx, this helped a lot and my project is finally moving forward!